# Como sacar una variable de un ciclo while en php

Tags: php, array, while

Hola he estado intentando sacar el resultado de un ciclo while, pero parece que lo estoy haciendo mal.

Hice una consulta a una tabla y esta me arroja tres resultados. Pero ahora quiero sacar esos resultados y guardarlos en una variable -como un array- fuera del ciclo. 
He intentado con este código (pero me arroja esto "Notice: Array to string conversion in ... on line 83"):

```
$datos = array();
$i = 0;


while ($resultados = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta)){

   $datos[$i] = $resultados;
   $i++;
 }

 echo $datos; /*linea 83*/
```

Comment: Hola, no puedes usar `echo` para mostrar el contenido de un array, puedes usar `print_r()` o `var_dump()` para eso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que se crearía en `$datos` sería un array, por lo tanto, no puedes imprimirlo con un `echo`, tendrías que:

- leerlo dentro de un bucle
- o bien indicar el índice y la clave a la que quieres acceder

Por otra parte, puedes simplificar tu código: no necesitas un contador `$i` ni indicar el índice cada vez, esto se hace sólo de forma natural.

Veamos:

### Código optimizado

```
$datos = array();
while ($resultados = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta)){
   $datos[] = $resultados;
 }
```

### Lectura

De acuerdo a la documentación `mysqli_fetch_assoc` produce un arreglo asociativo, donde la clave es el nombre de cada columna del `SELECT` y el valor es el dato que tenga esa columna.

Entonces, puedes leer `$datos` dentro de un bucle:

```
$allData="";
foreach ($datos a $dato) {
    $allData.="$dato[nombre] $dato[apellido]".PHP_EOL;
}
echo $allData;
```

Aquí concatenamos en `$allData` todas las filas y al final hacemos `echo`. Para aprovechas las comillas y no estar uniendo con `.`, pusimos los nombres de las claves sin comillas: `$dato[nombre]` y en el ejemplo asumimos que en los resultados había una columna llamada `nombre` y otra llamada `apellido`.

También puedes hacer `echo` directamente dentro del bucle:

```
foreach ($datos as $dato) {
    echo "$dato[nombre] $dato[apellido]".PHP_EOL;
}
```

Otra forma de leer los arrays es indicando el índice. Por ejemplo aquí estaríamos imprimiendo el nombre y apellido de la primera posición del array (índice `0` porque los arrays empiezan a indexar en `0`):

```
echo $datos[0]['nombre']." ".$datos[0]['apellido'].PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda A. Cedano

Answer (score 0):

No puedes imprimir con echo un array
En todo caso utiliza

```
print_r($datos);
```

Comment: puedes agregar mas información para mejorar la respuesta si gustas.